# How might I print onto 3×3 sticky notes?

Tags: printing

As cute as writing with Sharpies is, I'd like to print the findings from some user interviews onto sticky notes for affinity mapping. My reasoning is that printed characters are more reliably readable than handwriting. And if we've already typed our insights, I want to leverage them! So, are there any known ways to use a laser printer or similar to print onto sticky notes?

Comment: My solution for this is to mail merge, print on 8.5" x 11" paper, and use a paper cutter, then apply tape or push-pins to attach the notes to a surface.

Comment: See below for my updated solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later, I came across a solution: Printing onto clear labels 2.75" x 2.75". I mail merged to the template from Excel. My team and I used this method to create 2,000 sticky notes.

As epic as it was, I wouldn't repeat it. I'd use a tool like [MURAL](https://mural.co) that involve much less physical labor.

Answer (score 7):

Printable post it - found on e-bay. Tested. It works :)
Smaller ones are also useful!

[image]

Comment: I have done something similar that you can make yourself.  Use a standard label template or make your own template for placing the contents in the right location.  Mark the sticky note locations on a piece of heavy paper or card stock and stick blank post-its in those locations.  Then print on the sheet.  As long as the adhesive edge is fed first, there won't be a problem feeding it.

Comment: @fixer1234 I take it you've done this with an inkjet printer? I wouldn't want to risk it with a laser.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: I've done it with both.  Laser printers actually work better.  Post-its have some kind of coating and some inkjet ink takes a long time to dry.

Comment: @fixer1234 Fair enough. I've had issues in the past with certain labels peeling off the backing whilst being printed to on a laser; and have had to remove/disassemble their fusers a couple of times to get pieces of labels out, so as not to ruin the fuser/printer. Since then I use the manual feed tray whenever I print to labels, which seems to mitigate the problem.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Any kind of heavy or multi-layer stock works better with a straight feed path.  I'd hesitate to even use label sheets if they need to go through a path with tight bends.

Comment: A variation if your printer doesn't handle label stock well:  Use regular paper (colored if you like), and a template to print the notes.  Cut them apart and attach them using one of the many temporary glue sticks or roll-on adhesive dispensers.  Some extra steps but no printer problems.  If exactly 3x3 isn't required, you can use microperf stock that tears apart to various sizes, like index cards, business cards, etc.

Comment: Cool! Is "printable Post-It" the name of the product?

Comment: Do you recall what you paid for these bad boys?

Answer (score 3):

You can get A4 sized printable label sheets. Those you can print on using any standard printer. Just feed this special sheet into the tray.

You need to download a word table template with the right spacing & cell sizes.

Avery is a popular brand. Don't know the official name but I always thought of those as printable label sheets.

[e.g. see here](http://www.avery.com/avery/en_us/Products/Labels/Addressing-Labels/?Ns=Rank%7C0%7C%7CProduct%20Number%7C1)

Comment: Could you clarify what the product is called or add a link?

Comment: Read the question again. He's doing something that requires removable labels, not permanent ones.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have had glue from sticky notes and envelopes melt in my laser printer before, I would advise a different approach. (This is also helps with the fact that most larger laser printers I have seen won't print on anything smaller than 8.5 x 5.5 inches (half letter, approx A5 european size).

Print whatever it is you want to print, cut it out, and apply [Removable Restickable Glue](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GXFB4K) to one edge of the back of each cut piece. (That link is to 3M "Scotch" brand, but there are several other brands and you can find it at most office supply stores.)

This has an added benefit that you can vary the size and even the shape of the notes that you have if you desire to do that.

Comment: Your answer contains useful information, but there is such a thing as an inkjet printer.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch The question specifically mentions laser, so I answered for laser. I have been in many offices that only have laser printers, not inkjets, so lasers must be used.

Comment: This glue sounds promising.

Answer (score 0):

Make a blank Excel sheet, and use the border tool to put borders around all the cells.  Then, adjust the cell height and width so that they are exactly the height and width of Post-It notes.  This will likely take some trial and error.  Once you have it, print the sheet.  You should end up with a piece of paper that had a blank grid on it.

Next, type in each cell what you want to appear on the Post-It notes.  Carefully stick your Post-It notes on the paper, lining them up with the grid lines.  Load that sheet into your printer and when you print the Excel file, you'll have beautiful printed Post-It notes.

Please note that this will only work on an ink jet printer.  DO NOT try this with a laser printer.

Comment: Interesting—why not a laser printer?

Comment: I never actually tried it, but I'd be really concerned about the Post-It notes coming off and causing a jam.

Answer (score -4):

One useful tool I use is this ipad app called [Post it capture notes](http://www.post-it.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/PostItNA/Home/Ideas/Plus-App/)

It allows me to take  a photograph of the post it notes,categorize and then convert into a format for easy consumption.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Using this tool you can easily print it or share it any format used.

Comment: This is almost the exact opposite of what is being asked.

Comment: Great tool, but @Mokubai is correct. Think of mail-merging data from a spreadsheet to mailing labels. That's what I'm going for.